# Glowing Nixie tube

Tags: led, nixie

I'm looking to achieve a particular lighting effect in my next project:

[image] [image]

I've never worked with nixie tubes before so what I'm wondering is how the LED underglow works. Is it just an LED pointed at the base of the glass (is it glass?) which contains the nixie tube? Also, if anyone knows of a good tutorial on nixie tubes that would be great. I'm just using Wikipedia and such at the moment.

Comment: These are just made with a LED placed at the base of the tube.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you can buy nixie tubes sockets with in-built LEDs, that's how the glow is done.

http://www.nocrotec.com/shop/product_info.php/info/p27_IN-18-Nixie-tube-with-socket-and-blue-LEDs.html

Comment: Hm, ok... might build that myself with some smaller nixies. Thanks!

Comment: You can also drill a 5mm hole under the socket and insert  30 deg u ltrabright LED > 16 Cd @ 20 mA .  I have boxes of them